# Problem in calling postgres function from .net

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a function of day closing in postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transactions.start_eod_operation(
    value_date_ date,
    user_id_ integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM core.day_operation WHERE is_eod_completed = false AND value_date = value_date_) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'BOD for this date was never started.';
    END IF;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM transactions.transactions WHERE verification_status_id = 0) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Voucher(s) pending for verification, cannot perform EOD!';
    END IF;

    DELETE FROM history.balance_holder WHERE value_date::date = value_date_;
    INSERT INTO history.balance_holder(office_id, account_number_id, value_date, balance, minimum_balance, audit_user_id)
    SELECT 1, t.account_number_id, value_date_, SUM(COALESCE(t.credit,'0') - COALESCE(t.debit, '0')), p.minimum_balance, user_id_
    FROM deposit.transaction_view t
    INNER JOIN deposit.account_holders a ON a.account_number_id = t.account_number_id
    INNER JOIN core.deposit_products p ON a.deposit_product_id = p.deposit_product_id
    WHERE t.value_date <= value_date_
    GROUP BY  t.account_number_id, p.minimum_balance;

    PERFORM deposit.post_interest_transit(value_date_, user_id_);

    PERFORM deposit.auto_transfer_interest(value_date_, user_id_);

    PERFORM deposit.auto_transfer_fd($1, $2);

    PERFORM loan.post_interest_transit(value_date_);
    

    UPDATE core.day_operation SET is_eod_completed = true, eod_started_on=NOW(), eod_user_id = user_id_ WHERE value_date = value_date_;

END
$BODY$;
```

When user begin day close process from software

PERFORM deposit.post_interest_transit(value_date_, user_id_);  this function or command in this function run twice a day not every day when there is problem in connection or server computer performance or in normal condition too. Inside this
PERFORM deposit.post_interest_transit(value_date_, user_id_); function there is delete command if there is data exist in that day and only begin insert command but it inserting 2 times in table. There is not any problem if I ran this function directly from database twice or more. What is the solution is this postgres bug or web browser bug ?

Comment: If you call one function in two different places at the same time, it will post two times.

Comment: after posting first function there will not be the value deposit - withdrawal > 0 then how it will post two times?